# Why is it inserting a ? (question mark) right before Map entry?

Tags: c++, yaml, yaml-cpp

Yaml-cpp seems to be inserting a question mark right before my map entry. This is the outcome:

```
baryons:
  nucleons:
    - proton:
        quarkContent: [u, u, d]
        charge: 1
    - antiproton:
        quarkContent: [au, au, ad]
        charge: -1
    - neutron:
        quarkContent: [d, d, u]
        charge: 0
    - antineutron:
        quarkContent: [ad, ad, au]
        charge: 0
? hyperons:
    - lambda:
        quarkContent: [u, d, s]
        charge: 0
    - antilambda:
        quarkContent: [au, ad, as]
        charge: 0
```

As you can see, beginning with hyperons, there is a question mark. I tried adding more entries to see what happens. It seems to alternate between `?` and `:`. This is quite strange.

I tried removing all the contents of the nucleons key and the hyperons key, and I still get this

```
baryons:
  nucleons:
    - Hello
? hyperons:
    - Hello
```

Mmm. quite odd indeed. Here is my code. Forgive the messiness

```
#include "yaml-cpp/yaml.h"
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace YAML;

void addParticle(Emitter * e, std::string name, std::string qc1, std::string qc2, std::string qc3, int charge){
    *e << BeginMap << Key << name;
    *e << Value;
        *e << BeginMap;
        *e << Key << "quarkContent" << Value << Flow << BeginSeq << qc1 << qc2 << qc3 << EndSeq;
        *e << Key << "charge" << Value << charge;
        *e << EndMap;
    *e << EndMap;

    *e << BeginMap << Key << "anti" + name;
    *e << Value;
        *e << BeginMap;
        *e << Key << "quarkContent" << Value << Flow << BeginSeq << "a" + qc1 << "a" + qc2 << "a" + qc3 << EndSeq;
        *e << Key << "charge" << Value << charge * -1;
        *e << EndMap;
    *e << EndMap;
};

int main(){
    Emitter e;

    e << BeginMap;
    e << Key << "baryons";
    e << Value;

        e << BeginMap;
        e << Key << "nucleons";
        e << Value;
            e << BeginSeq;
            addParticle(&e, "proton", "u", "u", "d", 1);
            addParticle(&e, "neutron", "d", "d", "u", 0);
            e << EndSeq;
        e << EndMap;

        e << BeginMap;
        e << Key << "hyperons";
        e << Value;
            e << BeginSeq;
            addParticle(&e, "lambda", "u", "d", "s", 0);
            e << EndSeq;
        e << EndMap;

    e << EndMap;

    std::ofstream particlesYAML;
    particlesYAML.open("particles.yml");
    particlesYAML.write(e.c_str(), strlen(e.c_str()));
    particlesYAML.close();
    return 0;
};
```

On a side note, I'm indenting to reduce clutter. So forgive that too.

Also, is my YAML structure good? Or should I revise to something different? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're writing two successive maps as a single node when you really want a single map with two key/value pairs. Specifically (here's a snip of your code):

```
    e << BeginMap;
    e << Key << "nucleons";
    e << Value;
        e << BeginSeq;
        addParticle(&e, "proton", "u", "u", "d", 1);
        addParticle(&e, "neutron", "d", "d", "u", 0);
        e << EndSeq;
    // you previously had a EndMap and BeginMap
    e << Key << "hyperons";
    e << Value;
        e << BeginSeq;
        addParticle(&e, "lambda", "u", "d", "s", 0);
        e << EndSeq;
    e << EndMap;
```

The reason why yaml-cpp is giving you that extra `?`, instead of just giving an error, is that you actually don't need to provide `YAML::Key` or `YAML::Value`. Your code looks like:

```
e << YAML::BeginMap;
e << YAML::Key << "foo";  // specifies the key
e << YAML::Value;
e << YAML::BeginMap;      // specifies the value
// stuff
e << YAML::EndMap;
e << YAML::BeginMap;      // specifies a new key (the YAML::Key is implied)
// stuff
e << YAML::EndMap;
                          // no value is provided for that key
e << YAML::EndMap;
```

So you've got a map with two key/value pairs. The first is what you expected (the key is `foo`, and the value is a map). For the second, however, the *key* is a map and the value isn't provided, so it's interpreted as `null`. Since the key is a map, it must be a long-form key, which is designated with that extra `?`.

Side note: there's an `e.size()` that gives you the length of the output string so you don't need to use `strlen`.

Comment: Thank you! I thought that wouldn't affect it.

Comment: @user208020, I added an explanation of what's happening currently. By the way, if this helped you, I wouldn't hate an upvote or for you to select this as the correct answer :)